# Conditional select query not work when use order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I need simple select query.  In condition i pass a value, when sum of amount is grater than that value then return. if i pass 4 then return 2 row(**in picture ID-> 125,126**) because  sum(amount) of that 2 row  is 10 that grater than 4.

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

its work fine when by this query

```
SET @total:=0.0;

SELECT id,
       amount,
       price,
       @total := @total + Truncate((amount), 8) AS total_offers
FROM   table
WHERE  @total < 4;
```

**if i use order by then it not works**

```
SET @total:=0.0;

SELECT id,
       amount,
       price,
       @total := @total + Truncate((amount), 8) AS total_offers
FROM   table
WHERE  @total < 4
ORDER  BY price DESC;
```

**i need order by now how i solve this**

Comment: In recent versions of MySQL, optimizer may decide to `ORDER BY` before `SELECT` clause, and that would mess up the calculations if you are using user-defined variables.

Comment: Also, in your seemingly correct query, this looks suspicious: `WHERE  @total < 4`. `WHERE` happens before `SELECT`. so by that time, `@total` is not computed

Comment: Sum amount of row 1 is greater than 10 !?!?!

Comment: Why the rollback? Around here, we positively despise pictures of tables.

Comment: I think I've explained well enough

Comment: i think it is not more enough than picture, price and amount field are floating you are not use and i refer picture in description

Comment: I don't know what that means. Accordingly, the downvote stands.

Comment: @Masumbillah please explain the question further: `@total := @total + Truncate((amount), 8) AS total_offers` <- what is this for ? Your `where` condition is suspicious; you are asking to filter on `price` while you are using `@total` in `where`. Also, avoid using images.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya actually i need  output like picture. 1. desc by price.  2. sum(amount)<4. basically need top rows by price that total amount < 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work for you.

```
set @total:=0.0;
SELECT temp.id, temp.amount, temp.price, 
  @total := @total + Truncate(amount, 8) AS total_offers from (
     SELECT temp.* FROM table temp ORDER BY price DESC
  ) temp
where @total < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think since MySQL 5.6, you have needed to do the `order by` in a subquery when you use variables.  So, this should work:

```
SELECT id, amount, price, total_offers
FROM (SELECT t.id, t.amount, t.price,
             @total := @total + Truncate(amount, 8) AS total_offers
      FROM (SELECT t.*
            FROM table t
            ORDER BY price DESC
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @total := 0) params
     ) t
WHERE total_offers < 4;
```

Note that this also changes the comparison to use the variable.  The evaluation of variables in `WHERE` clauses is also indeterminate.

In MySQL 8.0, this is much more simply written as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (order by price desc) as total_amount
      from table
     ) t
where total_amount < 4;
```